# Why is the control not going inside the if loop while checking for characters?

Tags: java, if-statement

I had this program where I had to take the two numbers and a symbol from an expression like:

```
**111*369**
```

But here:

```
for(i=0; i<t; i++) {
while(w) {
    if(ar1[i].charAt(j)=='+' || ar1[i].charAt(j)=='-' || ar1[i].charAt(j)=='*' || ar1[i].charAt(j)=='/') {
        w = false;
    }
    else {
        k = ar1[i].charAt(j);
        a = a*10 + (long)(k-48);
    }
}
```

The program never goes to inside the if-statement. It gets into an infinite loop.

So why isn't it checking the symbols?

Here's the link for the complete program with the output: [My Program](http://ideone.com/CAMfEh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop always checks the same character in the condition, since you never increment `j`. Therefore, if that character is not an operator, the loop will never terminate.

You should increment `j` in each iteration, and take care not to increment `j` past the last index `ar1[i]` :

```
    while(w && j < ar1[i].length) {
        if(ar1[i].charAt(j)=='+' || ar1[i].charAt(j)=='-' || ar1[i].charAt(j)=='*' || ar1[i].charAt(j)=='/') {
            w=false;
        }
        else {
            k=ar1[i].charAt(j);
            a=a*10+ (long)(k-48);
        }
        j++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `while` statement:

```
while (w) {
    if (ar1[i].charAt(j) == '+' || ar1[i].charAt(j) == '-' || ar1[i].charAt(j) == '*' || ar1[i].charAt(j) == '/') {
        w = false;
    } else {
        k = ar1[i].charAt(j);
        a = a * 10 + (long)(k - 48);
    }
}
```

If the `if` condition is false, you go to the `else` block. The `else` block does nothing to change `w` and does nothing to change the things being tested by the `if`, so the loop continues forever.